# Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly Web Application VS2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, build

we have a Asp.Net MVC 2.0 application. In Vs2010 solution Explorer there is only a single System.Web referenced from the GAC (4.00). When I run the deploy project I am getting compile warnings stating "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly?" I opened our dll from our website with reflector and see 2 System.Web references also?

Comment: I found the error, I had to change the references in the project file to .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, I had to change the references in the project file to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur when you have a solution with multiple projects using the same reference but one of those references might be a different version. eg you have a solution with one project using entity framework 4.0 and another project using entity framework 4.3.1.

You can resolve this by making sure that all references in your projects are using the same version.